# Each row is an object in adodb?

Tags: php, adodb, ezsql

It's possible get each row as an object like in ezSQL?
For example, ezSQL returns(print_r($sql):

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [click_time] => 2011-09-12 17:30:06
        [referrer] => direct
        [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0
        [country_code] => EN
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [click_time] => 2011-09-14 23:45:35
        [referrer] => direct
        [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0
        [country_code] => EN
    )
)
```

But how to do that in adodb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADODB uses [resources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) rather than objects, so you would have to build the object yourself.

Not knowing what version or functions you are using to interact with ADODB, this is only a basic idea, and you need advance knowledge of the fields (unless you get the field list from the resource itself, which generally is possible):

```
$_GET['id'] = check_input($_GET['id']);
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM stats WHERE shorturl='{$_GET['id']}'";
$result1 = $myDB->Execute($query1) or die(GetDbError($myDB->ErrorMsg()));

$fields = array('click_time', 'referrer', 'user_agent', 'country_code', ...);
$obj = new stdClass;
foreach($fields as $field) $obj->$field = $result1->Fields($field);
```

What this does is create an object, create a member variable in that object (named with the field name from the database), and set that member variable to the value returned for that database field.